# Inner AsyncTask vs AsyncTask on seperate alone class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

This is more like an opinion and subjective question :

Which one is better, using inner class for an asynctask ?

Or,

A one on a seperate class and send it the views that need to be updated onPostExecute, and move them inside the constructor

?

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on your app architecture.
If the thread is used, for example, only within specific Activity, you can create it as an inner class. 
But if you want to create something centralized, for example you want to create one class which will open thread for all http requests in the app, it is more reasonable to create separate class.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer inner classes because it's easy to access to context scope (class fields or final local variables, method parameters) without passing fields values to constructors or to ASyncTask.execute(...)

Subclassing is useful when you create reusable code for example I have a ProgressBarAsyncTask wrapping create/show/progress so inner classes implement only the doInBackground where the business logic changes case by case (download, update database, call webservice)